# ASP.NET application update on IIS on Windows Server 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis, windows-server-2019

I installed an ASP.NET application (`.NET FW 4.0`) on `Windows Server 2019` and it works fine.

But when I try to update an application (just copy files to directory) then application do not want to start and it just tries to load. And after some multiple application pool recycling and `w3wp.exe` killing it starts working.

Same application update works correctly on previous version of Windows Servers.

Any suggestions why update stops the application ?

Comment: .NET 4.0 is out-of-support, isn't it?  Especially on Server 2019.  Any chance you could try an upgrade to something supported? Like 4.6.2 or above.

Comment: I second the motion to upgrade to a supported version of .NET. But also: you need to stop the application pool when you do a deployment. Just make that part of your deployment process. You did script out the deployment, right?

Comment: No, it must be .NET 4.0, on server latest version of .NET is installed.

Comment: Yes, tried to stop the pool and then copy files and started an pool but it didn't helped.